# OSGi injection of dependencymanager

Tags: osgi, apache-felix, felix-dependency-manager

I am trying to inject the `DependencyManager` into my component. The `BundleContext` is injected but the `DependencyManager` is not ([`@Inject`](http://felix.apache.org/apidocs/dependencymanager.annotations/r2/org/apache/felix/dm/annotation/api/Inject.html)). What am I doing wrong?

```java
import org.apache.felix.dm.DependencyManager;
import org.apache.felix.dm.annotation.api.Component;
import org.apache.felix.dm.annotation.api.Init;
import org.apache.felix.dm.annotation.api.Inject;
import org.apache.felix.dm.annotation.api.Start;
import org.osgi.framework.BundleContext;

@Component
public class InjectionExample
{
    @Inject
    BundleContext bundleContext;

    @Inject
    DependencyManager manager;

    @Init
    void init()
    {
        System.out.println("Bundle Context: " + bundleContext);
        System.out.println("Manager: " + manager);
    }

    @Start
    void start()
    {
        System.out.println("start");
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried with a "@ServiceDependency" annotation rather than a "@Inject" for the manager ?

Comment: Yes I have. I found the "problem". I used two versions of the dependency manager. Now I forced to one version it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the "problem". In my project 2 different versions of the the dependency manager where used. After forcing usage of one version it works.